# Using character class to format list of numbers to a Zipcode format

Tags: linux, shell-script, centos

I tried to format a list of numbers to a ZIP code format (five digits). I used the `sed` utility to do so. Let us say, `file.txt` contains "23232334", "3434654", "33532", "94607". In my script, I wrote:

```
sed -n '/^[0-9] [0-9] [0-9] [0-9] [0-9]$/p' file.txt
```

but it did not work.

I have also tried

```
sed -n '/^[[:digit:]] [[:digit:]] [[:digit:]] [[:digit:]] [[:digit:]]$/p' file.txt
```

Per my understanding of character classes, these steps should work but I don't know why I am not getting any output.

Please, help

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to format the numbers, or are you trying to extract the numbers that fit the zipcode format? If the latter, I would use `grep` as that's what it's for. You also show spaces between the digit selectors, so your patterns will only match digits with spaces between them.

Comment: Thank you so much.  It does work after removing the spaces.  I was able to extract the 5-digit numbers that I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons why your commands do not work. First off all you have spaces between numbers and `sed` looks for digits separated by spaces. Second, when you write `^` and `$` you require that the five-digits number should occupy the whole line, so out of four numbers in your example only the last two will pass the test. Is that what you want?